# GetObject(, "Word.Application") Office 365

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word, office365

After installing Office 365 my application code
in vba is not working anymore

```
Set wrd = GetObject(, "Word.Application") 
wrd.Visible = True  
wrd.Documents.Open "C:\My Documents\Temp.doc"  
Set wrd = Nothing
```

Does someone has any ideas

It does'nt recornize Office 365 with this code above 
but if i install Office 2016 or 2013 it works.

Comment: Search in the registry for correct application name. On windows 7 you can find it in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\RegisteredApplications".  Then replace the new name in "Set wrd = GetObject(, "Word.Application") ". Then it may work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED !

> Search in the registry for correct application name. On windows 7 you
>   can find it in
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\RegisteredApplicati‌​ons".
>   Then replace the new name in "Set wrd = GetObject(,
>   "Word.Application")

Thanks to @pavanc

It was called Word.Application.16 instead of Word.Application

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's just a markdown error on your part, but your code needs to separate lines:

```
Set wrd = GetObject(, "Word.Application") 
wrd.Visible = True
wrd.Documents.Open "C:\My Documents\Temp.doc"  
Set wrd = Nothing
```

If this doesn't help, maybe you can be more precise about the error you're getting?